# Limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{5}{x})^x$

Tags: calculus, limits

Estimate the value of $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{5}{x})^x$

I'm a little confused on how to do this problem, especially since the answer needs to have 4 decimal places.

Please Help

Comment: Well, you could write $1.0000$. And if you need more decimal places $\dots$.  Is the exponent $2$ really supposed to be $x$? If so the answer is $e^{-5}$. And if it is supposed to be $2x$, square.

Comment: @AndréNicolas you're right it is suppose to be $x$. Not 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want
$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{5}{x})^x$.

Since
$\lim_{y\to \infty}(1-\frac{1}{y})^y
= \frac1{e}$,
by letting
$y = \frac{x}{5}$,
we get
$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{5}{x})^{x/5}
= \frac1{e}$.

By raising both sides
to the 5-th power,
we get
$\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{5}{x})^{x}
= \frac1{e^5}$.

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer is correct.

Comment: This is how I would have done it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 1. when x goes to infinity the fraction goes to 0, so you're left with 1^2 which is 1

---

Since you've made an edit, the limit  $\lim_{x\to \infty}(1-\frac{a}{x})^x = e^{-a}$

Which in your case means the limit converges to $e^{-5}$

Comment: (The question was edited and the exponent is now $x$.)